# Zend Hostname Route dispatching defined controller / action

Tags: zend-framework, dns, routes

When a certain domain is requested, I would like to display page genereted by defined controller / action. I tried using hostname route (in this case requesting www.some-page.de should dispatch transportAction in IndexController), like this:

```
$hostnameRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(
    'www.some-page.de',
    array(
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action'     => 'transport'
    )
);

$plainPathRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static('');

$router->addRoute('transport', $hostnameRoute->chain($plainPathRoute));
```

Apparently I am doing something wrong, because it isn't working (instead indexAction of IndexController is being dispatched). Any hints or ideas how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it - it's very simple and I hope it is also good practice:

In a plugin's routeShutdown hook I check the domain name (using $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) and if it is the desired domain, I set the action name using following code:

```
$request->setActionName('transport');
```